# Use loops to generate new dataframes on Databricks Scala according to percentiles wanted

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Scala on Databricks. In my dataframe df, the first column is an ID, the second column is the date, and the following N columns are different measures.

I want to create a new dataframe that has the 99th percentile for each date of each measure

My code to do this is the following:

```
val p99_dataframe = original_df

.groupBy("date")

.agg(
callUDF("percentile_approx", $"measure1", lit(0.99)).as("measure1"),
callUDF("percentile_approx", $"measure2", lit(0.99)).as("measure2"),
callUDF("percentile_approx", $"measure3", lit(0.99)).as("measure3"),
(...)
callUDF("percentile_approx", $"measureN", lit(0.99)).as("measureN"),
)
```

All of the "measure" columns have the same structure of name (measure1, measure2, etc).

What I would like to know:

1. Instead of having to write one line for each measure, is it possible to have some kind of loop in which I inform the first part of name (measure) and then it loops for every measureN column that I have in my dataframe?
2. Is it possible to, instead of writing `lit(0.99))` and `p99_dataframe`, I use a variable in which I will write the percentile that I want (0.99, 0.50 or other) and that it will be automatically used to change the name of the dataframe generated and the percentiles in it?
3. Is it possible to have a list of percentiles that I want (0.99, 0.50 and others) and that list will be used as an input for a loop that will generate one dataframe for each of the percentiles in that list, all with names similar to p99_dataframe, p50_dataframe, etc?

I am quite new to Spark Scala and I am still trying to understand how to do loops using it. I have read the documentation but I still don't understand how to do any of these things.

Comment: supply all the code pls...makes life easier in terms of helping

Comment: why not use `df.summary` function with a list of percentiles that you need? Doing that in the loop is very expensive

Comment: Thanks! @thebluephantom I am sorry! I will try to do that later! Thanks for the tip!

@AlexOtt I didn't know about ```summary``` and that seems to be exactly what I wanted! Thanks!! Is there a way to do it with groupBy a certain column? I am trying ```df.groupBy("date"). .summary("99%").show()``` but I get the error ```error: value summary is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value summary'? .summary("99%","99.5%").show()```